# auto scroll chatbox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, chat

i have chatbox every 3 second update and overflow div(chatbody) . i want evry loop this function scroll div bottom?

my code

```
function chat()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("chatbody").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
I THINK CODE MUST BE HERE 
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","func/chat.php?tnow=" + (new Date()).getTime(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
setInterval("chat()",3000);
```

Comment: use http://nodejs.org/ for chat app. its good

Comment: You have to set scrollTop to chatbody equal of last child offset + height of it.

Comment: i want auto scroll code no chat webserver js

Comment: can u insert complete code here sergey?

Comment: in found this and work [autoscroll](http://fishcantwhistle.com/auto-scroll-to-bottom-of-div-javascript/#.T7SgxcgfG1s)

Comment: you can append <a name="newcontent1"> to the starting of data to be loaded in div(chatbody) and call the link chat.php?tnow=smthing#newcontent1. then it will go to that name automatically

Comment: You can change 'setInterval("chat()",3000);' to 'setInterval(chat,3000);'. You can pass functions to setInterval too and it is preferred and faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function chat()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("chatbody").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
     document.getElementById("chatbody").scrollTop = document.getElementById("chatbody").scrollHeight; //This scrolls the chatbox to the bottom/last
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","func/chat.php?tnow=" + (new Date()).getTime(),true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
setInterval("chat()",3000);
```

Hope this helps!